# Trying to get record when a correlated record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to get a record from a table, but only want to retrieve that record if there isn't another corresponding record with another status.

Schema:

ID: PK

RID: Collection ID

IID: Item ID

Each ItemID correlates to a record

An example of what the records could be:

| ID | RID | IID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 1000 | Available |
| 1 | 14 | 1000 | Deleted |
| 1 | 14 | 1001 | Available |
| 1 | 14 | 1001 | Deleted |
| 2 | 15 | 2000 | Available |
| 2 | 15 | 2000 | Deleted |
| 2 | 15 | 2001 | Available |

As you can see in the table for RID: 15, We have an IID which is Available and DOES NOT have Deleted.

I want to be able to select that row. Essentially I want to return only the record where and instance has an Available, but no corresponding Deleted record for that same instance.

Right now, I've been querying all of the data and then doing some business logic in code to determine it, but I would rather filter this at the database level.

I know I'm meant to be using a subquery but haven't got it working yet.

Any help appreciated, SQL isn't my strong point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM test t1
WHERE status = 'Available'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
      AND t1.RID = t2.RID
      AND t1.IID = t2.IID
      AND t2.status = 'Deleted'
    )
```

| ID | RID | IID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15 | 2001 | Available |

```
SELECT ID, RID, IID, 'Available' status
FROM test
GROUP BY ID, RID, IID
HAVING MAX(status = 'Available')
   AND NOT MAX(status = 'Deleted')
```

| ID | RID | IID | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15 | 2001 | Available |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2fcu0Eg6)

Comment: First one doesn't seem to work. From the results I am getting, I still get IID's that are available, BUT that IID did have a Deleted event.

Comment: Same with the bottom one

Comment: I only want to return the record if that IID only has an Available status and NO Deleted status

Comment: @magna_nz You do something wrongly. Fiddle added.

Comment: I think `AND NOT MAX(status = 'Deleted')` in the HAVING clause is unnecessary, as MAX(status = 'Available') will only get `Available` when the group does not have `Deleted`

Comment: @blabla_bingo You're wrong. After removing you'd receive all groups which contains at least one 'Available' regardless 'Deleted' presence.

Comment: @Akina, my apologies. I misinterpreted the `MAX(status = 'Available')` to be `max(status)='Available'`. If it were `max(status)='Available'`, I think it would be enough without the rest . Is there something harmful by using only `max(status)='Available'`  in the HAVING clause ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo I'd avoid the reference on the relative positions of the hardcoded values until the possible values list is restricted with these 2 values.

Comment: Right, there could be potentially more values than the currently displayed. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select *
from(
select *
  ,lead(Status,1,'Absent')over(partition by ID,RID,IID 
      order by Status)nextStatus
from test
)x
where Status='Available' and nextStatus='Absent'
```